# Facebook API - copy website products to facebook shop

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Please can someone point me in the right direction; I'm looking to show my website's products on my Facebook page's shop. Which API or resource should I be looking at to achieve this?

I'd prefer to be in control and manually code the API relationship between my website and Facebook, instead of using a third-party.

From my own research it appears I'd need to apply for the Shops API (alpha), however this has a couple caveats:

- It's in alpha; I'm unlikely to be accepted as facebook appears to be looking for big brands.
- Judging from the freely available docs, I'd need to pose as a merchent on my own platform.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/shops-api

Any advice is welcome, thank-you.

Comment: Hi ,
have you seen this link ?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch/guides/send-item-updates